# Node-soap with WSDL that imports another WSDL

Tags: wsdl, node-soap

I have a 2 WSDL files.

1. WSAPIService.wsdl
2. WSAPIServiceContract.wsdl

WSAPIService.wsdl references WSAPIServiceContract.wsdl another via an import tag.

```
<wsdl:import location="WSAPIServiceContract.wsdl" />
```

I was hoping node-soap would automatically pull in the referenced file, but it doesn't appear to be.

```
const client = await soap.createClientAsync('WSAPIService.wsdl')
```

Does anyone have experience with merging wsdl files or using node-soap with a wsdl with imports?

Thanks!

I have already tried:

1. https://github.com/pkielgithub/SchemaLightener - it failed with `Exception: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Too many nested template or function calls. The stylesheet may be looping.`
2. https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/muse/site/docs/2.2.0/manual/tools/wsdlmerge.html This looked helpful but the download links are broken

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!